# WPF ListView Binding ItemsSource in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, binding

I have a simple XAML page with a ListView on it defined like this

```
<ListView Margin="10" Name="lvUsers" ItemsSource="{Binding People}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Age" Width="50" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Age}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Mail" Width="150" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Mail}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

In the code behind I do:-

```
public ObservableCollection<Person> People { get; set; }

public ListView()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.People = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
    this.People.Add(new Person() { Name = "John Doe", Age = 42, Mail = "john@doe-family.com" });
    this.People.Add(new Person() { Name = "Jane Doe", Age = 39, Mail = "jane@doe-family.com" });
    this.People.Add(new Person() { Name = "Sammy Doe", Age = 7, Mail = "sammy.doe@gmail.com" }); 

}
```

If I set the ItemsSource of my listview in the code behind like this

```
lvUsers.ItemsSource = this.People;
```

it works and my grid is displayed as expected

However if I remove that line and try and bind in the XAML

```
<ListView Margin="10" Name="lvUsers" ItemsSource="{Binding People}">
```

it no longer works.

Why doesn't the binding in the XAML work?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you don't do it already, in XAML for example, you need to set `DataContext` for your binding. Also since `People` property does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` you might want to create this list before `InitializeComponent`, at very least before you set `DataContext`, to be sure list is ready when binding is evaluated. You can add to your `ObservableCollection` later but if you create it after that point without notifying UI it won't work

```
public ListView()
{
    this.People = new ObservableCollection<Person>();
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this;

    this.People.Add(new Person() { Name = "John Doe", Age = 42, Mail = "john@doe-family.com" });
    this.People.Add(new Person() { Name = "Jane Doe", Age = 39, Mail = "jane@doe-family.com" });
    this.People.Add(new Person() { Name = "Sammy Doe", Age = 7, Mail = "sammy.doe@gmail.com" }); 
}
```

Comment: I dont think list needs to be created before InitializeComponent() (and ObservableCollection already implements INotifyPropertyChanged). You are right about DataContext need setting though.

Comment: I this case it is true but OP might not want to initialize `DataContext` in code but in XAML for example and then if you do it after `InitializeComponent`, without `INotifyPropertyChanged`, it won't work.

Comment: Interesting. Didnt know that before :)

Comment: Anyway I've reworded my answer to give some more explanation

Comment: Yes that works, thanks.  Why don't I have to set the DataContext when I use the line lvUsers.ItemsSource = this.People in my source code?

Comment: Because then you don't use binding for `ListView.ItemsSource` but set it to local value which can be any `IEnumerable`. Binding works in binding context. It needs object to take that property from. Items will still use binding because `ListView` will set `DataContext` of each `ListViewItem` to item in your collection

Answer (score 7):

Put this line after the existing code in xaml.cs

```
this.DataContext = People;
```

and replace your xaml with

```
ItemsSource="{Binding People}"
```

to

```
ItemsSource="{Binding}"
```