# WPF ListView GridViewColumn Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, gridview, binding

I'm trying to bind items to a ListView in columns.

**XAML:**

```
<Grid>
<ListView x:Name="songList">
    <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Title" Width="200" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Title}"/>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

**Code behind:**

```
public List<MediaItem> mIList = new List<MediaItem>();

void refresh()
{
    songList.Items.Clear();
    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Library.MediaItem> i in ActiveLibrary.Items)
    {
        Library.MediaItem item = i.Value;
        mIList.Add(new MediaItem() { Title = item.Title });
    }
    songList.ItemsSource = mIList;
}


public class MediaItem
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

When refresh is called, I want the title of the MediaItem to be displayed in its own column (so that I can add other properties later).

At the moment, the GridView just shows the ToString() result:

[image]

Other questions have hinted that the solution is something to do with the DataContext, but I haven't found anything that works.

Thank you.

Comment: check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26353919/wpf-listview-binding-itemssource-in-xaml

Comment: I tried an ObservableCollection with get and set accessors instead and setting the data context to itself in the initializer. It still doesn't display columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - I eventually solved it.

I left the project for a while to focus on learning the MVVM design pattern and move away from old WinForms habits.

**When the MediaItem class inherits INotifyPropertyChanged (and raises PropertyChanged in the setter of the property), this works as expected.**

I'm not entirely sure why this was necessary, but it fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in the constructor:
this.DataContext = this;

```
this.DataContext = this;
```

In the XAML:

```
<ListView x:Name="songList" ItemsSource="mIList">
```

Use ObservableCollection instead of List.

Then, in the refresh method you won't need the first and the last lines.

Comment: I had to use ItemsSource="{Binding mIList}", which does the same as before