# How to add items in listview

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have ListView,and in the right side textBoxes,Combobox and Add Button, I need to add items in listview, everything seems ok, but when i debug it and clicking on button add,it give me error like this`
http://prntscr.com/ix7zgg

This is my WPF` http://prntscr.com/ix83xi

What have i written wrong?This is my code`
http://prntscr.com/ix81oe

```
<Window x:Class="Suren_WPF_Controls.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Suren_WPF_Controls"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="700">
<Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="listview" Margin="0,0,300,50">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Anun" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Azganun" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Surname}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Tariq" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Age}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Masnajyux" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Branch}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
    <TextBlock Margin="420 10 0 0" Text="Name"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="nametextBox" Margin="420,30,72,260"/>
    <TextBlock Margin="420 70 0 0" Text="Surname"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="surnametextBox" Margin="420,90,72,200"/>
    <TextBlock Margin="420 130 0 0" Text="Age"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="agetextBox" Margin="420,150,72,140"/>
    <TextBlock Margin="420 190 0 0" Text="Branch"/>
    <ComboBox x:Name="branchcomboBox" Margin="420,210,72,80">
        <ComboBoxItem>Painted</ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem> Not Painted</ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
    <Button x:Name="btnAdd" Content="Add" Click="btnAdd_Click" Margin="570,275,20,10"/>
</Grid>
```

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public List<User> users;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        users = new List<User>()
        {
            new User("Petros","Petrosyan",20,"Komitas"),
            new User("Poghos","Poghosyan",28,"Tigran Mets"),
            new User("Valod","Hakobyan",36,"Baghramyan"),
            new User("Mher","Simonyan",19,"Amiryan"),
            new User("Ruben","Kirakosyan",22,"Kentron"),
        };
        listview.ItemsSource = users;
    }
    private void add()
    {
        users = new List<User> { new User(nametextBox.Text, surnametextBox.Text, int.Parse(agetextBox.Text), branchcomboBox.SelectedItem.ToString()) };
        listview.Items.Add(users);
    }

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       this.add();
    }
}
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Branch { get; set; }
    public User(string Name,string Surname,int Age,string Branch)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Surname = Surname;
        this.Age = Age;
        this.Branch = Branch;
    }
}
```

Comment: If it says stopped working,there might be some code-errors..What did the debugger say ?

Comment: and please don't post sceenshot's of your code :( rather edit your post and add it there

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ix89hs
http://prntscr.com/ix89pf

Comment: `agetextBox` contains something that isn't an integer.

Comment: that is not what i'm asking for..when u debug,if there's any code-error,VS will point it out in code-editor...Or u can set breakpoints as well..And please don't post screenshots anymore,u are inviting downvotes urself

Comment: I edited @zackraiyan

Comment: What are you typing into the age text box before you hit "add"?

Comment: Don't know if @RonBeyer's pointed out issue is your issue or not but if it is just convert it to an integer `Convert.ToInt32(agetxtbox.Text)`

Comment: @zackraiyan That will also throw a `FormatException` for the same reason `int.Parse` does.

Comment: @RonBeyer I'm typing number for example 40

Comment: Is the OP using `int.Parse` ?? I didn't check as he posted a huge paragraph and before that,he just posted screenshots :( Sorry,i'll check now

Comment: @zackraiyan I have tried like that too, but it have given the same error

Comment: `listview.Items.Add(users);`. This probably is causing the issue. You are trying to add an item of type `List<User>` to your list. You need to add the user instead of the full list.

Comment: Your listView.ItemsSource is set to a list, which means you intend to store `User` objects in there. But in your `add` method you actually add a new `List` object to that list. Beside that, you actually change the original list to a new one every time - and add only an item into it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're trying to use two different mechanisms to add items into the ListView. One - is through the `ItemsSource` and the other one - through `Items` directly. In the constructor you assign a list to the `ItemsSource` but then you actually try to modify the items.

You have two options to achieve what you want:
 1. Use only Items, and add `User` instances directly to the `Items` property.
 2. Stick with DataBinding and use `ItemsSource`. Assign it to an `ObservableColleciton<User>` and in your `add` method just add an item to the underlying collection - that'll automatically populate the list with the added item. The following answer contains details about how to exactly wire it up: [WPF ListView Binding ItemsSource in XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26353919/wpf-listview-binding-itemssource-in-xaml)

Answer (score 0):

As other answer has suggested, you should use Observable Collection and bind that as the item source of your list view. 
You should use TryParse method for parsing the age, to avoid exceptions.
You should use try catch block for you Add method so that your application will not crash in case of exception. I am displaying the exception in a Message Box for now.

```
var users = new ObservableCollection<User>();

            private void Add()
            {
                try
                {
                    int age = 0;
                    if (int.TryParse(agetextBox.Text.ToString(), out int parsedAge))
                    {
                        age = parsedAge;
                    }

                    users.Add(new User
                    {
                        Name = nametextBox.Text,
                        Surname = surnametextBox.Text,
                        Age = age,
                        Branch = branchcomboBox.SelectedItem.ToString()
                    };
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
```